NPOI Word Document Setting Header Top Margin
I am using NPOI for docx files. Here is my simple code block.
using (FileStream wordFile = new FileStream("C:\\User\\Desktop\\wordtest\\testword.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(wordFile);

            IList<XWPFHeader> headers = doc.HeaderList;
            foreach (XWPFHeader headeritem in headers)
            {
               ...
            }}

After my researchs I think there should be some margin settings in the foreach loop but I couldnt find any. Is there any setting methods there or is there any other solutions to give margin-top  to header using NPOI?
